# What version of C++ is used in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, c++

I can't find the information on which C++ version is being currently used in bitcoin core project?
Is it decided for future releases somehow? How does the situation looks now?

The only thing I could find was [Pieter Wuille's](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/208/pieter-wuille) comment:

> Bitcoin Core is switching to C++11 in the upcoming 0.13 release. Meanwhile, C++14 is already standardized and C++17 is well underway. Stating that Bitcoin Core always uses the latest features seems like a strange statement.

It may look like some XY problem, so the reason I am asking is my GF is long time C++ dev and I am looking for resources to learn C++ to be able to understand bitcoin code. Her first question was which C++ version it's written in, as it supposedly doesn't make sense to learn older versions.

Comment: See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/16684 and the latest comment by MarcoFalke for the specific features (such as the filesystem).

Comment: "it supposedly doesn't make sense to learn older versions" I strongly disagree. Even learning C helps develop C++ acquaintance. And it's too early to consider C++11 obsolete. You might want to skip the parts calling the Boost library since they have "The long term future goal ... to remove Boost as a dependency" and replace it with newer C++ features

Comment: Thanks @darosior! Exactly what I was looking for. @MCCCS thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bitcoin Core:

- v0.1.0...v0.12.x: C++03
- v0.13.0...v0.21.x: C++11
- v22.0...: C++17

Comment: What particular language features are used from C++17 or even C++11?

Comment: Lots of them, and which one changes from release to release. IIRC, in the first few C++11 releases some features were avoided because they weren't well supported on all compilers despite nominally supporting C++11.